# avrdude: ser_open(): can't set com-state for "\\.\COM4"

Tags: arduino-ide, avrdude, compilation-errors

My Arduino code is not getting uploaded. It gives me "avrdude: ser_open(): can't set com-state for "\.\COM4" error. It worked literally 5 mins ago. now it doesn't work. I updated the drivers and stuff. I have a new Arduino and my code worked 5 mins ago. when i made some changes to the code It stopped working. I am using an (unofficial) Arduino Uno R3. the USB to UART chip's name is ATMEL Mega 16U2 2048 TW which I'm pretty sure is the Arduino mega chip?? my Arduino uses the ATMEL ATMEGA328P U. Please help
Thanks in advance, Paradox

Comment: maybe you installed the wrong driver ... what is `and stuff`?

Comment: Is another program open which uses the COM port? Did you try to reboot?